# My app crashes when rendered text input is null. Undefined error REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, rendering, textinput

How can I improve the below code so that the app is not crashing when the "input" value is null? I know the issue is with "const { input } = route.params;"
If I remove it and add some text input, and put it back, the app works. However, on refresh app will crash when the initial value is null. How to implement the if statement?

Here I am rendering "input", which is TextInput:

```
export const IznajmiScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const { input } = route.params;
  
  return (
    <>
    <SectionContainer>
      <Text>{input}</Text>
    </SectionContainer>
    </>
  );
  };
```

And here is my text input Screen:

```
export const OpciPodaciOglasInput = ({navigation}) => {
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
return( 
    <>
    <Button title="Save"
    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Rent a car", {input})}/>
   <InputContainer>
   <TextInput style={styles.input} 
    placeholder="300 maximum"
    multiline = {true}
    maxLength={300}
    onChangeText={(text)=> setInput(text)}
    returnKeyType='done'
    value={input}
    onSubmitEditing={()=>{
      navigation.navigate('Rent a car',{input});
      setInput("");
    }}
    />
    </InputContainer>  
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a ternary.

```
<Text>{input === null ? "" : input}<Text>
```

Comment: const { input } = route?.params || {}  intead of :const { input } = route.params; solved the isue

Comment: better check input?.length > 0

Answer (score 0):

I've been receiving the same error on iOS since upgrading expo/react-native/xcode.

The error in xcode points to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js` so for now you can patch this file yourself.

Open `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js` and edit line 105 `registration.listener.apply(...` to now read

```js
if (registration.listener) registration.listener.apply(...
```

then run `npx patch-package react-native` which will generate a file in `patches/` folder. Now run `npm install` and re-build the app. It's no longer crashing for me when expanding a TextInput.